# Disable laptop monitor when there is an external monitor

Tags: graphics, xorg, multiple-monitors, laptop, display

How can I configure Xorg so that when a certain external monitor is attached to my laptop via HDMI, that external monitor becomes the main monitor and the laptop monitor is switched off?

Obviously I would like the laptop monitor to switch back on when the external monitor is unplugged.

Also, if possible, I would like to have this behaviour to occur only when a certain monitor is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open the Displays settings and turn off the laptop display (Built-in Display on the picture below).

If you unplug your external monitor it will come back again. And of course if the HDMI monitor is re-plugged, the laptop display will turn off as expected.

[image]