# Disable laptop monitor when external monitor is plugged in, AND have it persist across reboots

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, display, gnome-classic

As described in the answers to [other questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445364/disable-laptop-monitor-when-there-is-an-external-monitor), I am aware of the "Displays" settings where I can disable my laptop monitor. That works fine.

However when I reboot, my laptop monitor is magically re-enabled and I have to go to the Displays settings and disable it again. Is it possible to make this setting persistent?

It used to work fine on 14.04, but for some crazy reason I upgraded to 16.04 and it hasn't worked since then. Also 14.04 had this nice behavior where if I turned on my laptop without my external monitor plugged in (or if I unplugged my external monitor), then the laptop monitor would turn on. I'd like a solution that maintains that functionality too.

I'm using gnome-session-flashback, if that makes a difference. Graphics are Intel HD Graphics 4000.

Comment: Is very well possible, but we'd need to automatically make it work *after log in*. Would that be an issue? Also: do you either connect or disconnect the external screen after log in?

Comment: After log in is fine, that's actually what it did on 14.04, sorry for not mentioning. Login screen would be on both monitors always. Usually I don't connect or disconnect after login, but sometimes I do and it'd be nice if that worked - it did on 14.04, it'd automatically enable/disable the laptop monitor.

Comment: I am on mobile currently, but did you see this one:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/740004/how-can-i-automatically-switch-off-internal-screen-when-an-external-screen-is-co/740140#740140 ?

Comment: I did something similar to that back in the dark ages when multiple monitor support on Linux was shitty, but I was hoping for a simpler solution like how 14.04 worked out of the box.

Comment: the issue is often that graphics drivers and screens don't understand each other, which makes settings jump to defaults. What I can offer is either a shortcut key (script) to apply an arrangement or one at startup. Alternatively the one in the linked question.